# Rename file as per barcode using windows cmd or batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, barcode-scanner, batch-rename

I have some scan images which having barcode i had found cmd barcode scanner tool

```
bardecode -f C:\input\file1.png -t code128 >> C:\output\output.txt
```

this will read the image file and save barcode number in output.txt file.

I want to make a process so this command run on each file in a folder and rename that file with its barcode first 3 or 4 digits.

i try for loop, it runs the command on all png files in folder and print output in file.

```
for %%i in (C:\input\*.png) do bardecode -f %%i -t code128 >> C:\output\output.txt
```

but i want to use output to rename that file.

Comment: Use a 2nd stacked `for /f` to directly parse the output instead of saving it to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understood well, with no layout to test, I image the loop to do this.

If possible, please, provide barcode.exe output layout, without this, there no much references to perform test.

Please note that I need to know the layout of `output.txt` to improve my code:

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0" & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('dir /b /a-d C:\input\*.png') do ( 

     for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('"bardecode.exe" -f "!_name_!" -t code128') do (

         set _full_name=%%~fi
         set _name_only=%%~ni
         set _bar_code_to_rename=%%I
         set _bar_code_to_rename=!_bar_code_to_rename:~0,4!-!_name_only!
         ren "!_full_name!" "!_bar_code_to_rename!.png"

        )    

    )
```

Comment: Did you consider that as you rename each file in the inner loop, it may be reassessed by the outer loop, and inevitably cycle back to the inner loop again. Also, I would suggest that the renamed file would need to still carry the images extension. As you're using delayed expansion, there should be no need to use `Call Set`, just `Set` should be sufficient.

Comment: Please check the last page of `cmd /?` to see all of these special characters.

Comment: @Kaputz, moving from the initial nested loop structure to a single loop and `Call`ed label with another loop has actually not improved your code, it has made it worse. _Other than now including the original extension, as I previously commented, you have not dealt with the other things I highlighted_. When each file is renamed, _i.e. when the script returns from the `Call`ed label_, I would expect that the newly named file will be identified as `*.png`, as parsed by the original loop. You also seem to still be using `Call Set` when `Set` is all that's needed.

Comment: zOk, but no cloud of layout from barcode output! Btw, call set is paranoia!!